# Async with reference lambda crashing

Tags: c++, asynchronous, lambda, crash

I'm curious as to why this would crash in around 1 runs in 4.

I have a simple class that returns a string with a thread id. 
This class is called from within another class asynchronously in a lambda and returns the result. The code is as simple as I can make it - I'm still learning:

```
class String_Returner
{
public:
    string run() const
    {
        return "I returned from thread "+to_string(this_thread::get_id());
    }
};

class Class_Holder
{
public:
    Class_Holder() : number_of_runs(10)
    {
        srs.resize(number_of_runs);
    }

    void concurrent_srs()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_runs; i++)
        {
            results.push_back(async([&]{return srs[i].run();}));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << i << ") " << results[i].get() << endl;
        }

        results.clear();
    }
private:
    vector<future<string>> results;
    vector<String_Returner> srs;
    const int number_of_runs;
};

void class_b_test()
{
    Class_Holder ch;
    ch.concurrent_srs();
}
```

I realize using async with a reference is dangerous, but I figured it'd be safe if nothing is being written. I think my error probably comes from the lambda itself. This is mainly a programme to test the functionality of async and lambdas.

So my main questions:
1) Why is it crashing?
2) What better ways are there to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why is it crashing?**

```
results.push_back(async([&]{return srs[i].run();}));
```

There's nothing wrong with the reference to `srs` in that line; as you say, it is not being modified. But the reference to `i` is completely meaningless; `i` may no longer exist when the lambda executes, and its value will be unpredictable.

But I don't understand why you feel the need to have more than one `StringReturner`. The class has no state, and the `run` method might as well be static for all the difference it makes.

**What better ways are there to do this?**

Do what, exactly?

Comment: The main point of the programme is to test lambas and concurrency. i not existing may well be the key here. If I pass i as a copy, not a reference, that should work, right? I guess I'll go try :)

Comment: @David: You could either pass `i` as a copy, or you just just always use the same lambda. I don't see how having two lambdas referencing two different instances of a stateless class tests anything. If you wanted to see that different StringReturner objects were being referenced, you'd have to put some state into the object so that the lambdas visibly referenced different objects.

Comment: I'm still learning about lambdas, thats where this whole issue comes from. Basically I was aware that stuff was passed as a reference, but didn't even think about 'i'. Ive done some reading on the subject today. I'll accept this answer as it is closest to what I was asking for.

Comment: results.push_back(async([&, i] {return srs[i].run();})); - This was the fix I used, simply marking i as a copy and everything else as a reference. Now I'm trying to find a way to do the same without a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a lambda anyway, why not just use one that directly does what you want:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() { 
    std::vector<std::future<std::string>> rets;

    auto f = []() {
        std::ostringstream b;
        b << "returned from: " << std::this_thread::get_id();
        return b.str();
    };

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        rets.emplace_back(std::async(f));

    for (auto & t : rets) {
        t.wait();
        std::cout << t.get() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Note that the `thread::id` type that `get_id` returns is guaranteed to have an `operator<<`, but at least as far as I know, there's no guarantee that it's a type for which `std::to_string` has been overloaded.

Comment: This looks interesting. Thanks for the reply.